# celery 2.x @periodic_task's not showing up in task registry

Tags: python, celery

I've recently updated to celery 2.0 and I'm trying to use the new (to me) decorators for periodic tasks:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(days=1))
def some_task(**kwargs):
    #task here
```

I also have some other code is my site that lists periodic tasks and how often they run using

```
from celery.registry import tasks
```

to get the list of tasks. My issue is that tasks added using the decorator don't seem to show up in this list of tasks. Is there a way to get a list of tasks added using the decorators in celery 2.0?

Comment: Maybe the task modules haven't been loaded yet? If you're using Django then you should run `djcelery.loaders.autodiscover` before building a list of the tasks.